# Cauchy's residue application problem

Tags: residue-calculus

I would like to know what did I do wrong. There's my problem :

I= $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ $\int_a \frac{1}{z^4+1}~dz$

Where a  $x^2 + y^2 = 2x$

I already know: there're 4 poles, but only 2 fits for me (right ones):  $e^\frac{i\pi}{4}$ and  $e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}$

I've both residues:
-$\dfrac{1}{4}$$e^\frac{i\pi}{4}$ and $\dfrac{1}{4}$$e^\frac{-i\pi}{4}$

$\sum\limits_{b=1}^2 z_b$ = $\dfrac{ -\sqrt{2}}{4}$i

But correct answer is given without i. What's wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: So your contour is $|z-1|=1$?

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Yes.

Comment: If that's so then the imaginary part of the residues cancel out as you have typed and when you multiply with $2\pi i$ you should have imaginary result.

Comment: According to my calculations the answer should be $\frac{\pi i}{\sqrt{2}}$. At least you forgot to multiply by $2 \pi i$.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Sorry, I didn't get your mind. Correct answer is given without imaginary result.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Correct answer : 

I= -sqrt(2)/4

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Can you give me extended solution ? I can't f ind my mistake :) BTW answer is negative

Comment: You have wrong poles. You took the ones from the right. You should take them inside the circle which is in left half-plane.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen $e^\frac{i\pi}{4}$ and  $e^\frac{i5\pi}{4}$?

Comment: $e^{i \pi/4}$ and $-e^{3 i \pi/4}$

Comment: Sry for the confusion. You should take them from RIGHT side of the plane. And calculating the residue of those above and adding up gives you the correct result. (which indeed is negative). You can pretty much forget everything above. Messed up with left and right lol.

Comment: @HartoSaarinen Thank you anyway. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contour $C:$ $|z-1|=1$ is in the right half-plane. The poles of integrand are $-e^{i \pi/4}, -e^{3 i \pi/4}, e^{i \pi/4}$ and $e^{3 i \pi/4}$.

Two of those are inside $C$: $e^{i \pi/4}$ and $-e^{3 i \pi/4}$. Calculating the residues and summing them gives $-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{4}$.